# Sudo Gnome Disk break shutdown and usb mount

Tags: unity, permissions, shutdown, usb-drive

I have been reinstalling my system about 7 times. And I think it's time to ask.

Everything in my ubuntu was working fine until I disable the automount in gnome-disk (with su permission). Then I couldn't shutdown the pc using the button (shutting down using command line sudo shutdown still working).

And I lost the permission to mount any storage as well.

I do believe there are folders and files that the root has took over from me, but I don't know which one. I'm wondering what files that gnome-disk change and might modify.

it's crazy that I've been stuck in the same issue 7 times.
I'm using ubuntu desktop 16.04 lts and gnome-disks 3.18.3.1

If someone could give me some direction would be much appreciated

Comment: I added an answer, please check if it works for you and/or report possible issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is about running `gnome-disks` as *root* and with `sudo`. This software is intended to be run as normal user *(in contrast to gparted and others)*.

- You can simply and cleanly disable automount running:

  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false`
- You can also disable *auto-open* feature independently from automount with:

  `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false`

If you feel uncomfortable with terminal, you can install `dconf-editor` with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`. Start it from *Unity* and graphically navigate to *org.gnome.desktop.media-handling* and change its value.

If you want more info check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) wiki link.

Hope it helps.